# Does Velocity Engine support vm templates with french language

Tags: apache, velocity

I am working on a application which has templates in english language. This templates are used as email templates for messages. Now we are adding support for french language due to which need to create new templates with french language. So does velocity engine supports french language?

Answer (score 1):

I think it will support, you may need to setup proper encoding for this.
[this link](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/developer-guide.html#template-encoding-for-internationalization) may help you